# can we deduce an argsort array from numpy's unique function?

Tags: python, numpy

[From the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html)

> Returns the sorted unique elements of an array. There are three optional outputs in addition to the unique elements: the indices of the input array that give the unique values, the indices of the unique array that reconstruct the input array, and the number of times each unique value comes up in the input array.

Therefore, `numpy.unique` must be performing a sorting algorithm.  Is there a way to deduce the sorted-ness from the outputs of `numpy.unique`.  Asked another way, can we derive the same results of an `argsort` purely from the output of `numpy.unique` so I don't have to sort twice.

---

Consider arrays `a` and `b` as sample data.

```
import numpy as np
from string import ascii_letters

np.random.seed([3,1415])
n = 10000
a = np.random.randint(100, size=n)
b = np.random.choice(list(ascii_letters), n)
```

Comment: Would you be dealing with integer numbers? Are there duplicate numbers in the array?

Comment: I'm thinking of a general solution given just the output from `unique`.  I'll post sample data in a minute.

Comment: @Divakar updated post

Comment: Look at the code; it's Python.  `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py`.  It does a `sort` or `argsort` depending on whether you ask for indices.  The rest is basically a `diff` looking for duplicates.

Comment: @hpaulj can you add an answer so I can up-vote it and accept it?  Thx

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote my own unique function

```
def unique(a):
    s = a.argsort()
    a_ = a[s]
    return a_[np.append(True, (a_[1:] != a_[:-1]))], s
```

---

***timing***
@hpaulj is correct.  Notice that my custom `unique` is just as fast as `np.unique` when `np.unique` is asked to return an `inverse` array.  Otherwise, when it just returns `unique` values, it is a bit faster.

[image]

Comment: Hi @piRSquared, is it possible to adjust this solution to also return the inverse array without performing a second sort?